# Delphi XE7 TBannerAd not showing ad on Android

Tags: android, ios, delphi, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to test run some admob ads via the TBannerAd component in Delphi xe7, to see if it will work on ios and android.

Upon testing the ad seems to load on IOS but on Android nothing happens.

I've checked the manifest file and made sure it had the activity and meta data. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Could someone shed some light?

Comment: There was the same question on a german forum and a solution http://www.delphipraxis.net/181702-probleme-mit-tbannerad-unter-delphi-xe7.html

Comment: I've l seen that tried the manifest solution still not working unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Just checking the obvious - have you enabled the AdMob Service option on the entitlements page in the project options?

The entitlements page is new in Delphi XE7, so may not have been set up, and so won't pull in the required Google advertising library into the final binary. This will cause a lack of functionality, despite the manifest file looking fine.

See [online documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Entitlement_List) for more details.