# Delphi XE7 - FMX Android - Entitlement List missing from Project Options

Tags: android, delphi, admob, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to add AdMob ads to my FMX Android application. I have a problem with the following step from [Using AdMob Instructions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_the_AdMob_Service#Configuring_the_Connection_Data_for_AdMob):

> Go to Project > Options > Entitlement List, and select AdMob Service. Set its value to True.

My problem is that I can't find `Entitlement List` in my project options

[image: My Project options]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: And how are the instructions for my XE7 ?

Comment: XE7 has AdMob support and component BannerAd is avilable
but application fall down on BannerAd.LoadAd;

throw exception:

First chance exception at $A2B4C495. Exception class EJNIException with message 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />'. Process nz.apk (10361)

Comment: OK. So the error tells you exactly what you need to do to fix the problem, which is edit the AndroidManifest.xml. See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Preparing_an_Android_Application_for_Deployment#Customizing_Your_AndroidManifest.xml_File

Comment: Yes but I try added this tag into my AndroidManifest.template but then compilator report error:
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').

Comment: Yes, you have to replace the part after `value=` with the Android version you're targeting - it's an **integer**, as it says, and an attribute, which means it goes inside double quotes. Have you ever thought of reading the Android documentation at Google?

Comment: But I do not understand the meaning of this value ? What android version ? I placed as value 4 but now error was .... excepted value is 4323000 what that means ?

Comment: Read the documentation. I'm not going to keep doing it for you.

Comment: i place line  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4323000" />'. to manifest, application is compilable, runable but Ad not shown. UnitID and call BannerAd1.LoadAd; I have on form show event

Comment: in this post is the same problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701808/delphi-xe7-tbannerad-not-showing-ad-on-android/39429518?noredirect=1#comment66182483_39429518